# Python -Class 'set' comparison

Tags: python, csv

I am using csv reader to pull a value from column 3 of a file.
I wish to compare this value (num) to the values in set "days", to see if the number is present or not. It always returns "False", even when it should return TRUE. type() returns " <class 'set'>" for both days and num. What am I missing?

```
from csv import reader
from csv import DictReader
import csv
import sys
days={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

def main():
    import csv
    with open('TC.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            num={row[2]}

            print(num)
            #print(type(num))
            days={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
            #print(type(days))
            test=num in days
            print(test)
        if test:
            print('DO SOMETHING') 
        
        else:
            print("DONE")
    
            csv_file.close()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It returns:
'''
{'3'}
False
{'5'}
False
{'8'}
False
{'8'}
False
{'13'}
False
'''

TC.csv------------------------------------------

163,5-Apr-21,3,8-Apr-21,00,-5,-15,85,105,30,50,65,35,0,15,-40,-15,N,Y,N,6.2,2,Y,26,-10,L,60,'YELLOW',MOD,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
164,5-Apr-21,5,10-Apr-21,00,-10,-20,150,170,10,65,90,-25,-15,-55,0,-65,N,N,Y,6.2,2,Y,29,-10,L,70,'RED',HIGH,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
166,5-Apr-21,8,13-Apr-21,00,10,20,180,-160,0,120,0,-25,-55,-55,0,-35,N,N,N,7.2,2,N,28,14,L,60,'YELLOW',MOD,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
167,5-Apr-21,8,13-Apr-21,00,5,15,130,150,20,80,25,-15,-5,-45,-56,-45,N,Y,Y,7.2,2,Y,29,-14,L,70,'RED',HIGH,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Because there are no `set` objects in the set `days`... it contains `int` objects. So basically you should use `num = row[2]`, although note, it will be a `str`, so really, you need `num = int(row[2])`....

Comment: As an aside, re-defining `days={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` on each iteration sort of defeats the purpose of fast lookups. Also, there's no point to use `csv_file.close()`... you used a `with` block, the whole point of the context manager is to close the file automatically

Comment: num = int(row[2]) Is what I needed. Many Thanks!... now back to work for me.